# SAS: Enhanced Editor. Color Scheme Sharing

Tags: editor, sas, color-scheme

I have a color scheme for enhanced editor in SAS 9.2.

How can i share this scheme with others?

Where does file of scheme be found?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The editor coloring scheme is stored in SAS registries.
You can export and import registry entries to share the scheme definitions.

There is a SASHELP and SASUSER (user defined) part of registry. I didn't try it, so I'm just guessing - based on whether you modified original color scheme or defined your own, it's stored in either SASHELP or SASUSER part. For that, you may need to use or not use `USESASHELP` option of `PROC REGISTRY` to export the definition.
Here's how you do it.

```
proc registry export="C:\eeditor_scheme.sasxreg"
               startat="CORE\EDITOR\SCHEMES" usesashelp;
run;

proc registry import="C:\eeditor_scheme.sasxreg";
run;
```

Anyway, modifing the registry is a low-level intervention to the system, so I recommend you make a full backup of your registry before importing a registry file:

```
proc registry usesashelp export="C:\reg_backup_sashelp.sasxreg";
run;
proc registry export="C:\reg_backup_sasuser.sasxreg";
run;
```