# Exporting / Importing SAS Enhanced Editor color schemes

Tags: sas, themes, editor, enterprise-guide

In [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629731/sas-enhanced-editor-color-scheme-sharing), a solution was given to export registry entries pertaining to the editor schemes. However, the solution seems relevant only to the **old** Program Editor used in earlier SAS Display Manager versions, not to the Enhanced Editor used both in SAS Enterprise Guide and more recent versions of SAS DM.

What is stored in the SAS registry, as far as I can tell, are solely schemes not even available to the Enhanced Editor: *Indianapolis*, *Nashville*, *Miami*, and so forth. Neither the provided themes for the Enhanced Editor, nor the user-created schemes show up in the full SAS registry export (described in the aforementioned post.)

They must then be elsewhere... but where? I did some digging in the AppData directories, as well as in the *sasuser* and *sashelp* libraries, finding *nada*. So my question is: does anyone on earth know where these schemes are stored?

It takes quite a bit of work to configure a scheme that really suits one's preferences, so it would be very useful to be able to back it up in case something goes wrong, and to share it with envious colleagues.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are in this key if using EG 7.1:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAS Institute Inc.\Enhanced Editor\BIC_7.1

I have a scheme called MyCustomScheme. Here's what my registry looks like:

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thanks a whole lot! :)